# Problems with basic prototyping in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, prototype

i am kinda new to javascript and i started off on something where i am stuck with some basics, the thing is i am trying to create an prototype for an object and then the references of created objects in an array and then accesing their methods but i am wrong somewhere can anyone help me with this, what i am doing is shown here :-

```
function Obj(n){
    var name=n;
}
Obj.prototype.disp = function(){
    alert(this.name);
};
var l1=new Obj("one");
var l2=new Obj("two");
var lessons=[l1,l2];
//lessons[0].disp();
//alert(lessons[0].name);
```

but none of these methods seem to work out.... :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You not assigning a property of the `Obj` object, but just have a local variable inside the constructor. Change like this:

```
function Obj(n){
    this.name = n;
}
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6tafK/)

Comment: You posted the same solution 7 seconds before me :) +1

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is with the constructor, you are assigning the parameter to a local variable not to a field variable, change it like:

```
function Obj(n){
    this.name=n;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks a lot i completely forgot that , it works thank you very much

Comment: @user1860959 If an answer solved your problem, mark it as such by clicking the checkmark right next to it (upper left).

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
 function Obj(n){
        this.name=n;
    }
```

**REASON:**

Difference between `var name=n;` and `this.name=n;`

**var name=n;**

The variable declared with `var` is local to the constructor function. It will only survive beyond the constructor call if it's used in some method inside the object

**this.name=n;**

this is property of the object, and it will survive as long as the object does, irrespective of whether it's used or not.

Example:[`this` in javascript](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/)